# Flask Api In Azure App Service returns 404 Not Found

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

Hi everyone i hope you all are doing Great,

my situation :

i deployed a flask api in azure app service

Using Deployment Center with [my git repo](https://github.com/ossamasgr/flask)

when testing the code in local everyting seems to work as expected but in azure app service
every url with "url/something" returns :

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
> entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

my code :

```
    def convert(file):
    with open(file, encoding='utf_8') as xml_file:
        data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
        xml_file.close()

        # generate the object using json.dumps()
        # corresponding to json data

        json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)

        # Write the json data to output
        # json file
        with open("CvTest.json", "w", ) as json_file:
            json_file.write(json_data)
            json_file.close()

        with open('CvTest.json') as f:
            d = json.load(f)
        df = pd.json_normalize(d)
        df = df.to_dict('records')
        df = pd.json_normalize(df)
        data = df.to_json("file.json", orient="records")

    with open('file.json', 'r') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    for element in data:
        element.pop('cv.@xmlns', None)

    for element in data:
        element.pop('cv.binaryDocuments.document', None)
    with open('templates/data.json', 'w') as data_file:
        data = json.dump(data, data_file)

    with open('templates/data.json', 'r') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    output = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["cv.personalInformation.firstname",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.lastname",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.gender.code",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.gender.name",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.title",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.isced.code",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.isced.name",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.birthyear",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.civilState"
                                         "cv.personalInformation.address.street",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.address.postcode",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.address.city",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.address.country.code",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.address.country.name",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.address.state",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.email",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.phoneNumber",
                                         "cv.personalInformation.homepage",
                                         "cv.work.phase",
                                         "cv.work.additionalText",
                                         "cv.education.phase",
                                         "cv.education.additionalText",
                                         "cv.additionalInformation.language",
                                         "cv.additionalInformation.competences",
                                         "cv.additionalInformation", ])
    output.to_csv('data.csv')
    return jsonify(data)


UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "templates"

if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY)


api = Flask(__name__)


@api.route("/files")
def list_files():
    """Endpoint to list files on the server."""
    files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY):
        path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            files.append(filename)
    return jsonify(files)


@api.route("/files/<path:path>")
def get_file(path):
    """Download a file."""
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, path, as_attachment=True)


@api.route("/files/<filename>", methods=["POST"])
def post_file(filename):
    """Upload a file."""

    if "/" in filename:
        # Return 400 BAD REQUEST
        abort(400, "no subdirectories allowed")

    with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, filename), "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(request.data)
    return convert(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY,filename))
    # Return 201 CREATED
    return "", 201


if __name__ == "__main__":
    api.run(debug=True)
```

requirments :

> Flask==2.0.2 xmltodict==0.12.0 pandas==1.3.4

[image: deployment in github]

it's my first time working with app service in azure

i hope someone can guide me to the right direction

thank you

Comment: What url are you using?

Comment: In Azure Portal, restart the web app and check once.

Comment: Instead of '@api.route' , change it to '@app.route' and check once

Comment: ok i'll try changing to @app.route

Comment: @C.Nivs im using the web app url https://apitest1712.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT i changed '@api.route' to '@app.route' but still the same issue

Comment: Add '/' after the folder name . Instead of @app.route("/files") , change it to @app.route("/files/").Restart the app  and browse the URL.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT you shouldn't have to add a `/` after the route

Comment: Are you behind a proxy at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but deploying the webapp from azure cli instead of Deployment Center worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have not configured the start up command in Azure.

my file `main.py` goes as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Then, on Azure Portal:
[Configuration > General Settings > Startup command:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyojb.png)

`python main.py`